# Make different slides line up

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, align

Let us say that you have the following in your presentation:

```
\begin{frame}
  Identical text
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{equation}
    \mathbb R
  \end{equation}
  Identical text
  \begin{equation}
    \int
  \end{equation}
\end{frame}
```

How can I make sure that "Identical text" is at the same position for each slides, without manually inserting `\vspace`'s that are exactly as large as the equation?
I don't want "Identical text" to jump around if I show the next slide.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Make a single frame with overlay specifications, see e.g. [the tutorial on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Beamer_Presentations:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_4)%E2%80%94Overlay_Specifications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\onslide<2>{%
  \begin{equation}
  \mathbb R 
  \end{equation}
  }
  Identical text
\onslide<2>{%
  \begin{equation}
    \int
  \end{equation}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```